# Separating SSL Certificate with Python RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I have a SSL certificate file that contains the Certificate Body, Certificate Chain and Encrypted Private Key, e.g.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
...
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
        -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
...
...
...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I'm looking to separate it into it's three different parts using Python's RegEx library, re.

I tried many different things, e.g `re.split(r'(-----BEGIN .+?-----(?s).+?-----END .+?-----)', exportCertificateOutput)`

Any advice on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Someone might ding you for this. Anyway `re.findall('[\-]{3,}[\S\ ]+?[\-]{3,}([\S\s]+?)[\-]{3,}[\S\ ]+?[\-]{3,}', exportCertificateOutput)`.  Or  `re.findall('-----[\S\ ]+?-----([\S\s]+?)-----[\S\ ]+?-----', exportCertificateOutput)`  It's not optimized, but this is problem is really simple, so it will do.

Comment: @FailSafe Thanks! What would I change to make it include the BEGIN and END lines for each of the three parts?

Comment: Either this `re.findall('([\-]{3,}[\S\ ]+?[\-]{3,}[\S\s]+?[\-]{3,}[\S\ ]+?[\-]{3,})', exportCertificateOutput)` Or  this `re.findall('(-----[\S\ ]+?-----[\S\s]+?-----[\S\ ]+?-----)', exportCertificateOutput)`

Comment: @FailSafe This matches as intended when I use a RegEx tester like regex101.com. But when I do it in Python with the re library, I get an error about an "Anomalous backslash in string. String constant might be missing an r prefix" before each of the backslashes in the in the regular expression.

Comment: There are 2 different regexes. Which one gives you an error?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @FailSafe I ended up going with:

```
re.findall("(-----[BEGIN \S\ ]+?-----[\S\s]+?-----[END \S\ ]+?-----)")
```

Please note you may have to escape the `\` by doubling them `\\`.